# Looping through XML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, loops, robohelp

I've got some basic code that can loop through some XML that's generated from Adobe RoboHelp (for our help documentation). This works fine, but since a topic could be nested as many time as the writer wants, i need a better way to loop through this XML rather than just nesting `.each()` loops.

Here's what the XML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--RoboML: Table of Content-->
<roboml_toc>
  <page title="Welcome" url="Welcome.htm"/>
 <book title="Getting Started" url="Getting_Started/Initial_Setup.htm">
   <page title="Initial Setup" url="Getting_Started/Initial_Setup.htm"/>
   <page title="Customize Settings" url="Getting_Started/Settings.htm"/>
 </book>
 <book title="Administrator Services" url="Administrator_Services/General_Administrator.htm">
  <book title="Portal Workspace" url="Administrator_Services/Portal_Workspace/AdminHome.htm">
    <page title="Home" url="Administrator_Services/Portal_Workspace/AdminHome.htm"/>
    <page title="Portal Accounts" url="Administrator_Services/Portal_Workspace/Portal_Accounts.htm"/>

  </book>
  <book title="SpamLab" url="Administrator_Services/SpamLab/SpamLab_Admin_General.htm">
    <page title="Alerts" url="Administrator_Services/SpamLab/Alerts.htm"/>
    <page title="Spam Quarantine" url="Administrator_Services/SpamLab/Admin_Spam_Quarantine_.htm"/>

  </book>

 </book>
 <book title="User Services" url="User_Services/General_User.htm">
  <book title="Portal Workspace" url="User_Services/Portal_Workspace/Home.htm">
    <page title="Home" url="User_Services/Portal_Workspace/Home.htm"/>
    <page title="Self Help" url="User_Services/Portal_Workspace/Self_Help.htm"/>
  </book>
  <book title="SpamLab" url="User_Services/SpamLab/SpamLab_General.htm">
    <page title="Spam Quarantine" url="User_Services/SpamLab/Spam_Quarantine.htm"/>
    <page title="Virus Quarantine" url="User_Services/SpamLab/Virus_Quarantine.htm"/>
  </book>

  <book title="Encryption" url="User_Services/Encryption/Encryption_General.htm">
    <page title="Outlook Plug-in" url="User_Services/Encryption/Encryption_Outlook_Plug_in.htm"/>
  </book>
 </book>
</roboml_toc>
```

A `<page>` is an article, and a `<book>` is a folder.

Her's my jQuery code, which only can look one level deep of  tags

```
   //Get the TOC
$tocOutput="";
$.get(tocURL,function(toc){
    $(toc).children().each(function(){
        $tocOutput+="<li><a href='"+$(this).attr("url")+"'>"+$(this).attr("title")+"</a>";
        if(this.tagName=="BOOK"){
            $tocOutput+="<ul>";
            $(this).find("page").each(function(){
                $tocOutput+="<li><a href='"+$(this).attr("url")+"'>"+$(this).attr("title")+"</a></li>";
            });
            $tocOutput+="</ul>";
        }
        $tocOutput+="</li>";
    });
    $("#list").html($tocOutput);
```

I know there's a better way to just loop through all elements and then determine if the element has children, etc. but I just can't think of how to do it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just curious - why must this be done on the client?  Why not apply an XSLT transformation on the server and send down the html?  Is the xml dynamic?  Could the transformed html not be cached on the server?

Comment: Regardless, glad you found a solution - NOW ACCEPT KEITH'S ANSWER :)

Comment: I REFUSE!  This was just a proof of concept for now.... actually I just wanted to impress some people. They are showering me with praise now, so it's worth it.  Eventually I think we will be doing this server side though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recursive functions work well for this. When you create a function that creates and uses an internal recursive closure you can wrap it all up in a neat little package:

```
    $.get(tocURL, function(toc) {
    function makeToc($xml) {
        // variable to accumulate markup
        var markup = "";
        // worker function local to makeToc
        function processXml() {
            markup += "<li><a href='" + $(this).attr("url") + "'>" + $(this).attr("title") + "</a>";
            if (this.nodeName == "BOOK") {
                markup += "<ul>";
                // recurse on book children
                $(this).find("page").each(processXml);
                markup += "</ul>";
            }
            markup += "</li>";
        }
        // call worker function on all children
        $xml.children().each(processXml);
        return markup;
    }
    var tocOutput = makeToc($(toc));
    $("#list").html(tocOutput);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`$(el).children().length` which would return '0' or a positive number, then loop through if it's a positive number which evaluates to true. You could also use a while loop to do this recursively, and re-set the reference handler however I'm not quite sure that would work out because your nodeNames for each subsequent child differ ( or do they? ) .. What's the most nested example you can provide?

Comment: No, the node names are either <book> or <page>.  A page can exist inside or outside a book.  A book can contain other books or pages.

In the XML I posted above there's a page that has 2 book parents.

Answer (score 1):

THanks so much Keith, that was the ticket - well almost, I had to make one MINOR change and then it worked perfectly!

My code is below.

```
$tocOutput="";
$.get(tocURL,function(toc){
 function makeToc($xml) {
  // worker function local to makeToc
  function processXml() {
   console.log($(this));
   $tocOutput += "<li><a href='" + $(this).attr("url") + "'>" + $(this).attr("title") + "</a>";
   if (this.nodeName == "BOOK") {
    $tocOutput += "<ul>";
    // recurse on book children
    $(this).children().each(processXml);
    $tocOutput += "</ul>";
   }
   $tocOutput += "</li>";
  }
  // call worker function on all children
  $xml.children().each(processXml);
 }
 var tocOutput = makeToc($(toc));
 $("#toc").html($tocOutput);
 completed($("#toc"));
});
```

You'll notice all I'm doing is declaring the variable outside the `$.get()` and then I use `$xml.children().each(processXml);` instead of `$(this).find("page").each(processXml);`
that you had.

The reason for this is that the children could be pages **OR** books, but what you had was limiting it to only pages.

Thanks again!

Comment: You can thank me by accepting my answer! Incidently, my goal wasn't to solve your whole problem, just to duplicate the logic in your question. Also, I placed the variable declaration inside makeToc() as a general best practice. Doing it that way makes it clear that variable is only for the use of makeToc to accumulate results.

Answer (score 1):

This link provides a good example for use of iterating through xml
http://anasthecoder.blogspot.in/2012/02/looping-through-xml-with-jquery.html

```
xml.find('result').find('permissionDetails').each(function(){
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        var tagName=this.tagName;
        var val=$(this).text();
        if(val==1){
            $('input:checkbox[name='+tagName+']').attr('checked',true);
        }
        else if(val==0){
            $('input:checkbox[name='+tagName+']').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to earn some more praise. I made it an anonymous function call, and used the arguments.callee to recurse. I was myself looking for this method, this and another thread at stackoverflow helped me out and I want to pay it back :-)

```
$.get(tocURL,function(data){
    var markup = "<ul>";
    $(data).each(function(){
        markup += "<li><a href='" + $(this).attr("url") + "'>" + $(this).attr("title") + "</a>";
        if (this.nodeName == "BOOK") {
            $markup += "<ul>";
            $(this).children().each(arguments.callee);    
            $markup += "</ul>";
        }
        markup += "</li>";
    });
    $("#list").html(markup+"</ul>");
});
```