# Traversing all nodes of an XML doc with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

How would I traverse an XML doc of unknown structure, so as to perform an operation on every node, using jQuery?

I'm looking for some sort of recursive function whereby I could access each node, check for sub-nodes, and repeat.

Comment: Yarin:
Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574113/looping-through-xml-with-jquery) be your answer? Edit: See user meder's answer for nodes with unspecified depth or titles.

Comment: Agreed!  +1 to maenu.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is basically a [depth-first-search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). You could do something like this:

```
var depthFirstTraversal = function($root, callback) {
    $root.children().each(function() {
        depthFirstTraversal($(this), callback);
    });
    callback($root);
};
depthFirstTraversal($(selector), function($node) {
    // do stuff with $node
});
```

Edit: Made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mr3Ym/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var xml = "<xml></xml>";
$("#xml").html(xml);
</script>
<div id="xml"></div>
```

Comment: @Peter- My question was ill-put- See my edit: I need to be able to access each individual node, not just dump the whole thing into html